# Determine from code if Core Data framework is present

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I have a class that I need to use in both Core Data and non Core Data applications. In non Core Data applications I need the class to omit certain code at compile time. Are there any compiler directives that detect if Core Data framework is added to the Xcode project, something like #ifdef __COREDATA?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way:

```
#if NSCoreDataVersionNumber
//my code
#endif //NSCoreDataVersionNumber
```

And

```
#ifdef _COREDATADEFINES_H
  //my code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just test for a class and see if it's defined.

```
if ([NSFetchRequest class] == nil)
```

Comment: I need to test at compile time not run time.

Comment: why do you need it at compile time?